# php mysql nontrivial tables meaning?

Tags: php, mysql

what does it mean if a php/mysql table is nontrivial? I need to create a nontrivial php mysql table and I'm not even sure I know what that is.

Comment: There's no off-topic vote for "belongs on english.stackexchange.com" :)

Comment: @Michael: Just vote it to close as it'S "off-topic"

Answer (score 2):

[Nontrivial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontrivial) is the opposite of trivial. And trivial is something that is easy. So nontrivial is something that is difficult to achieve. So probably the person who told you that creating this MySql table will be nontrivial he meant that it is not going to be easy. But that's really off-topic for this site.

Comment: ah, I thought that but then I figured it would be too easy and thought there was some sort of secret coding meaning behind it! LOL

Answer (score 2):

I think a useful definition for "non-trivial" to keep in mind is a "general case which does not suffer degeneracies and includes 'typical' features".

For example, a non-trivial configuration of two lines in a plane would be two crossing lines, but *not* two lines on top of each other.

For database purposes, suppose you want to test your new "DISTINCT" query. A non-trivial dataset would include repeated values, since you typically expect to encounter those. A table with all unique values would be a legal dataset, but you couldn't tell a DISTINCT query from a non-distinct one by its result set on such a table. So your dataset should have examples of all the features that you are expecting and writing a handler for.